# MySQL sum each X rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need little MySQL help. I have a table with hourly values like that:

```
ID | VALUE | HOUR
1  | 1.0   | 01.00
2  | 1.0   | 02.00
...
24 | 1.0   | 24.00
```

Now I have found that sometimes the data which i get is not on hourly bases but it is for every 30 Minutes or sometimes for every 15 Minutes. So the data can look like this:

```
ID | VALUE | HOUR
1  | 1.0   | 01.00
2  | 1.0   | 01.30
...
48 | 1.0   | 24.00
```

I need to display the data in hourly format, so I am curious if there is any chance to tell MySQL to sum each two (for 30 Minutes format) or each four (15 Minutes format) rows of the result ?

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: The hour part. Is that a string...numeric..?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `FLOOR`(Rounds down) or `CEIL`(Rounds up) , depends what you prefer :

```
SELECT FLOOR(t.hour) as rounded_hour,
       SUM(t.value) as your_sum
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY FLOOR(t.hour)
```

E.G.

```
1.0
1.2
1.75
1.9
```

Will all turn into 1 .

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you:

```
Select ID,sum(Value),sum(Hour),substr(hour,1,2)as h group by h;
```